# Storing time intervals efficiently in redis

Tags: redis

I am trying to track server uptimes using redis.

So the approach I have chosen is as follows:

1. server `xyz` will keep on sending my service `ping` indicating that it was alive and working in the last 30 seconds.
2. My service will store a list of all time intervals during which the server was active. This will be done by storing a list of `{startTime, endTime}` in redis, with key as name of the server (`xyz`)
3. Depending on a user query, I will use this list to generate server uptime metrics. Like % downtime in between times (T1, T2)

Example:
assume that the time is `T` currently.

1. at T+30, server sends a ping.
   `xyz:["{start:T end:T+30}"]`
2. at T+60, server sends another ping
   `xyz:["{start:T end:T+30}", "{start:T+30 end:T+60}"]`

and so on for all pings.

This works fine , but an issue is that over a large time period this list will get a lot of elements. To avoid this currently, on a ping, I pop the last element of the list, check if it can be merged with the latest time interval. If it can be merged, I coalesce  and push a single time interval into the list. if not then 2 time intervals are pushed.

So with this my list becomes like this after step 2 : `xyz:["{start:T end:T+60}"]`

Some problems I see with this approach is:

- the merging is being done in my service, and not redis.
- incase my service is distributed, The list ordering might get corrupted due to multiple readers and writers.

Is there a more efficient/elegant way to handle this , like maybe handling merging of time intervals in redis itself ?

Comment: Both of your problems can be addressed by moving your adding-and-merging into a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) and executing that on the Redis server, where it will run as a single atomic command.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry thanks! looking into this.
Is there another data structure better suited for my usecase ?

Comment: I'm not sure offhand. A lot has been written about doing range queries in databases, though most of that concerns SQL. One thing that springs to mind is that these are binary, discrete, ordered values, so you could really just represent this as a string of bits, with each bit representing a half-hour interval (so every 48 bits is a day). In any case, start with the queries you want to do (i.e. the metrics you want to display) and then work backwards from that to find the best data representation.